# How can I conditionally override the field description?

Tags: 7, forms

I am using the [Reference Field Option Limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit) module in Drupal 7 and I want to change the explanation text that says:

> No options are available for the current form values..

I want to  put instead:

> Please select a value below.

I tried `hook_form_alter` but the new phrase is appearing even when there is an option selected in the matching field, which is not what I want. So any idea which hook function should I use?

PS: I don't want to change that from the module core.

Comment: Look at the module's code, there the description only gets added if a certain condition is met: [reference_option_limit.module#L538-542](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/reference_option_limit/-/blob/7.x-1.6/reference_option_limit.module#L538-542). You need to find out how this condition got calculated and do the same in your form alter hook. And yes, of course you don't hack the module.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code you have so far?